# Azue Map Search: unique ID and normalized name

Tags: geocoding, azure-maps

I use azure maps for cities autocomplete on my site.
I use this API method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/search/getsearchaddress

Request: `https://atlas.microsoft.com/search/address/json?params` and parameters are:

- `query=mosco` - I'm looking for Moscow
- `typehand=true`
- `api-version=1.0`
- `subscription-key=...my key...`

Result is

```
{
    ...
    results: [
        {
            type: "Geography",
            id: "RU/GEO/p0/116970,
            ...
            address: {
                municipality: "Moscow",
                countryCode: "RU",
                freeformAddress: "Moscow"
            }
        },
        ...
    ],
}
```

Ok, it's Moscow.
But I have a few questions.

1. What is `id`? Doc say it is "property id". It is persistent? Moscow will always be "116970"?
2. How can I get normalize name of a city?
   I can write "Москва" (Moscow in Russian) and it works and `id` is same, but names in the object `address` are different (`Москва, Moscow`).
   If I write "mos" then `id` is same but `address` is "Moskva" (instead Moscow).

Can I get `name` of a geo object by `id`?

Answer (score 1):

1. This is a unique id but is not guaranteed to be persistent. The main purpose of this id is for debugging purposes.
2. We are aware of the "en" issue and are updating the docs.

Comment: rbrundrift, thank you for answer! Is there way for unique determine geo object (I need only cities)? Pair countryCode+name is not unique as can be some cities with same name in one country.

Comment: Not really, all things change eventually. A change of a city names is not uncommon in the world.

Answer (score 0):

1. I sure this is a unique ID, but want proof from documentation :)
2. Problem solved by parameter `language=en-GB` now result always is "Moscow". I was misled by the manual when specified only `en` (it leads to error). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/supported-languages